# Help with Bug #1605230 ? We have to use sudo to access DFS subfolders when we shouldn't

Tags: sudo, root, nfs

We are experiencing an issue basically identical to the one described here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1605230

After some kind of OS update (kernel?) we suddenly need to use "sudo" to access any of the sub-folders in our DFS.

Are there any known work-abounds for this bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help ... Don't know what your `fstab` looks like but for mine with ntfs drives I have it like this:

`UUID=63243C176F24E783 /acronis ntfs defaults 0 2`

and I'm able to access the drives and subfolders from Windows and Ubuntu with no issues

Comment: The question appears to be about nfs - not ntfs

Comment: it was an example